# Hibernate program errors

Tags: java, hibernate

I am following this tutorial using eclipse EE : [hibernate-tutorial-for-begin](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/03/hibernate-tutorial-for-beginners.html). There are the errors I am getting. One more thing is that I couldn't find all mentioned jar files in any one hibernate distribution, so I have all jars from `openlogic-hibernate-3.3.1.GA-all-bin-1` & `lib/jpa` from `hibernate-release-4.0.0.CR5` bec it was not included in 3.3.1. 
I made tables in MySql.

**EDIT**
Here is list of Jar files I am using:

```
lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
lib\slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar
lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar
lib\commons-collections-3.1.jar
lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
lib\hibernate3.jar
lib\hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar
lib\hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.0.CR5.jar
lib\javassist-3.4.GA.jar
lib\jta-1.1.jar
lib\slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar
```

Here are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hib.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at com.hib.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:7)
    at com.hib.Test.addUser(Test.java:61)
    at com.hib.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.<clinit>(LoggerFactory.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:151)
    at com.hib.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:11)
    ... 3 more
```

Here are program files:

**Test.Java**

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class Test {

 /**
  * @param args
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Test tst = new Test();

  /**
   * adding records
   */
  tst.addUser("Saranga", "Rath");
  tst.addUser("Isuru", "Sampath");
  tst.addUser("Saranga", "Jaya");
  tst.addUser("Prasanna", "Milinda");

  tst.addTask(1, "Call", "Call Pubudu at 5 PM");
  tst.addTask(1, "Shopping", "Buy some foods for Kity");
  tst.addTask(2, "Email", "Send birthday wish to Pubudu");
  tst.addTask(2, "SMS", "Send message to Dad");
  tst.addTask(2, "Office", "Give a call to Boss");

  /**
   *  retrieving data
   */
  tst.getFullName("Saranga");

  /**
   * full updating records
   */
  User user = new User();
  user.setId(1);
  user.setFirstName("Saranga");
  user.setLastName("Rathnayake");
  tst.updateUser(user);

  /**
   * partial updating records
   */
  tst.updateLastName(3, "Jayamaha");

  /**
   * deleting records
   */
  User user1 = new User();
  user1.setId(4);
  tst.deleteUser(user1);
 }

 private void addUser(String firstName, String lastName) {

  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   User user = new User();

   user.setFirstName(firstName);
   user.setLastName(lastName);

   session.save(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void addTask(int userID, String title, String description) {

  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   Task task = new Task();

   task.setUserID(userID);
   task.setTitle(title);
   task.setDescription(description);

   session.save(task);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void updateLastName(int id, String lastName) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();
   String hqlUpdate = "update User u set u.lastName = :newLastName where u.id = :oldId";
   int updatedEntities = session.createQuery( hqlUpdate )
   .setString( "newLastName", lastName )
   .setInteger( "oldId", id )
   .executeUpdate();

   trns.commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }

 }

 private void updateUser(User user) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   session.update(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void getFullName(String firstName) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();
   List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User as u where u.firstName = :firstName")
   .setString( "firstName", firstName )
   .list();
   for (Iterator<User> iter = users.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    User user = iter.next();
    System.out.println(user.getFirstName() +" " + user.getLastName());
   }
   trns.commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }

 private void deleteUser(User user) {
  Transaction trns = null;
  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
  try {
   trns = session.beginTransaction();

   session.delete(user);

   session.getTransaction().commit();
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   if(trns != null){
    trns.rollback();
   }
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally{
   session.flush();
   session.close();
  }
 }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package com.hib;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
 private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
  try {
   // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  }
  catch (Throwable ex) {
   // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
   System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
   throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
  }
 }
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <!-- Database connection settings -->
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/userdata</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password"></property>

  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

  <!-- SQL dialect -->
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

  <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

  <!-- Mapping files -->
  <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="task.hbm.xml"/>

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**task.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.hib.Task" table="tasks">
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="userID">
   <column name="user_id" />
  </property> 
  <property name="title">
   <column name="title" />
  </property>
  <property name="description">
   <column name="description"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.hib.User" table="users" >
  <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
   <generator class="native"/>
  </id>

  <property name="firstName">
   <column name="first_name" />
  </property>
  <property name="lastName">
   <column name="last_name"/>
  </property>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Task Class**

```
package com.hib;

public class Task {

 private Integer id;
 private Integer userID;
 private String title;
 private String description;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public Integer getUserID() {
  return userID;
 }
 public void setUserID(Integer userID) {
  this.userID = userID;
 }
 public String getTitle() {
  return title;
 }
 public void setTitle(String title) {
  this.title = title;
 }
 public String getDescription() {
  return description;
 }
 public void setDescription(String description) {
  this.description = description;
 }
}
```

**User Class**

```
package com.hib;

public class User {
 private Integer id;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

 public Integer getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(Integer id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
}
```

Comment: When do you get the errors? When you run which code? Don't make us go through the whole tutorial! :)

Comment: I get errors when I compile code. I have two mysql tables & main file enters & retrieves values from it.

Comment: You get those errors when you *compile*?!

Comment: I thought it will be easy for you guys to mimic code from tutorial pages bec its just a typical heloworld program, but will consume a lot of space if I put all files here.

Comment: I edited OP & put all source.

Comment: You get these errors when you compile?!

Comment: Right now it looks like you're mixing up a bunch of different releases/libs/etc. Please deploy only the libraries you need; AFAIK the hibernate full release does include all libs necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runtime exception you've got is caused by [`slf4j`](http://www.slf4j.org/) (logging framework used by Hibernate). Make sure that you have provided the correct implementation that matches the slf4j API Hibernate was compiled with in your classpath, e.g. for Hibernate 3.3.1 (according to [pom](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/3.3.1.GA/hibernate-parent-3.3.1.GA.pom)) the correct version is [1.5.2](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.5.2/slf4j-simple-1.5.2.jar) (choose the target logging mechanism, e.g. simple/log4j/jdk14, according to your environment).

Comment: I listed the jars I am using in OP. As I mentioned in my OP, I added all jars from 3.3.1 & only lib/jpa from 4.0.0. Does it have some issue also?

Comment: You have different versions of slf4j and slf4j-simple - that might be a problem, API might have changed

Comment: @Igor Nikolaev: Right, the jars are slf4j-simple-1.6.4.jar & slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar. It will be same if either both are 1.6.4 OR 1.5.2 ??

Comment: You need to upgrade you slf4j jar to version 1.6.4, as version 1.5.2 tries to get field StaticLoggerBinder.INSTANCE which is missing in version 1.6.4 of slf4j-simple

Comment: @enterprize: Using both 1.6.4 should be just fine. Otherwise (bad luck) you can't use JPA from 4.0.0 – you have to upgrade Hibernate core to 4.0.0 as well.

Comment: @Igor Nikolaev, dma_k: thank you very much. I have no words to thank you :-)

Comment: @enterprize: Upvoiting is a nice way to show your appreciation :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not compile-time error, it's run-time. You are missing slf4j-log4j12.jar binding or other, depending on what underlying logging framework you want to use.

You can download it from http://www.slf4j.org/

Comment: but tutorial is only mentioning slf4j-api & slf4j-simple jars.

Comment: You didn't have a list of jars when I first wrote my answer. slf4j-simple and slf4j-log4j12 are just different underlying logging frameworks. And you can use only one of them else slf4j will issue an error as it doesn't know which one to use

Answer (score 0):

try to add `hibernate-jpa-xxx.jar` into your classpath. 
Verify the database connection configuration as well.